# How to create Common Blazor Component Library with version 3.0.100

Tags: blazor

How can we create a "common" Blazor Component library with version 3.0.100 ?
Formerly to 3.0.100 we could use:

```
dotnet new blazorlib -o <some project output name>
```

But this entry does not exist any more by default, i've tried next:

```
dotnet new -i Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates
dotnet new blazorlib -o BlazorPOC.Lib
dotnet sln add BlazorPOC.Lib\BlazorPOC.Lib.csproj
```

This creates a library project in .NET Standard 2.0 into the solution which makes references to next NuGet:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Browser" Version="0.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Build" Version="0.7.0" PrivateAssets="all" />
</ItemGroup>
```

But ... when I build i get :

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       rzc generate exited with code 1.    BlazorPOC.Lib   C:\Users\emmnuy\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.build\0.7.0\targets\RazorCompilation.targets    184
```

This does not work out. So my question is, how to i create a reusable component library for blazor which can be shared and referenced from within a .NET Core 3.0 based Blazor App.

Thx for your feedback !

Emmanuel Nuyttens

Comment: Did you update templates with the latest version ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Razor Class Library template` is now set up for Blazor component development by default and the `Blazor Class Library template` has been removed in favor of new Razor Class Library projects.

From the command line use: `dotnet new razorclasslib`